# Prevent USB device to be used by specific application in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, usb, skype, kinect

I am developing a Windows 7 application that uses Microsoft Kinect, plugged via USB.

This device also includes a microphone, and everytime I use Skype and plug in the Kinect, Windows 7 automatically assign this device to Skype (I can use it as a microphone in any call indeed).

The problem is that, if Kinect is used by Skype, I cannot test my application, because the Kinect must be exclusively assigned to my application.

So what I am looking for is a way to prevent Windows 7 from automatically assigning a device (in my case the Kinect, that is an USB device) to a specific application (in my case, Skype).

How can I do this?

Comment: You could look at how some Audio related applications like `Cubase` can "hijack" the audio ports so that none other application can use them.

Comment: If the Kinect is assigned to my app before starting Skype, Skype will not be able to make videocall (also with another webcam!), and you cannot use the microphone... it is an absolute no-sense

Comment: I also tried to use another microphone for the Skype call, but Kinect continues to be assigned to Skype, also if I don't actually use it!